# Error while copying content to a stream. (blobClient.UploadAsync())

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am sending a request to my API with
`content-type: multipart/form-data` .
In this request I have `IFormFile` property.
Here is my controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBlobUploadService _blobUpload;

        public HomeController(IValidator<SubmitFileRequest> validator, IBlobUploadService blobUpload)
        {
            _blobUpload = blobUpload;
        }

        [HttpPost("SubmitFile")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitFile([FromForm]SubmitFileRequest request)
        {
            _blobUpload.UploadFile(request.File);

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am sending the `request.File` property to `BlobUploadService`. Here is the code:

```
public interface IBlobUploadService
{
    void UploadFile(IFormFile file);
}

public class BlobUploadService : IBlobUploadService
{
    private string blobConnectionString = "my connection string";
    private string blobContainer = "my container";

    public async void UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(blobConnectionString, blobContainer);

        var blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);

        await using (Stream? stream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

In this line `await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream);` I keep getting the same exception.

> System.AggregateException: 'Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (Error while copying content to a stream.) (Error while copying content to a stream.) (Error while copying content to a stream.) (Error while copying content to a stream.) (Error while copying content to a stream.) (Error while copying content to a stream.)'

> Inner Exception 1: RequestFailedException: Error while copying content to a stream.

> Inner Exception 2: HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.

> Inner Exception 3: ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.

How do I fix this?
Thanks!

**UPD:**
Exception only occur when I use asynchronous version of Upload method. I recently tried to use it without awaiting and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> The errors "RequestFailedException: Error while copying content to a stream" and "HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream" suggest that it is an issue with the stream that you are trying to upload.
> The inner exception "ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream" confirms this.

Code to dispose the stream.

```
using (Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream);
}
```

Disposing the resource after the upload is complete, prevents the "Cannot access a closed Stream" error from occurring.

You can wrap the stream in a using statement to ensure that it is properly disposed of after the upload is complete.

```
public class BlobUploadService : IBlobUploadService
    {
        private string blobConnectionString = "my connection string";
        private string blobContainer = "my container";
        public async void UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(blobConnectionString, blobContainer);
            var blobClient = container.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);

            using (Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream);
            }
        }
```

[image]

For further information, check this [MSDoc.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload.md)